# Apache: require basic auth, except for specific POST requests

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, lamp

(RHEL 6.2, Apache 2.2.1)

I'm trying to get a LAMP site running behind basic auth to prevent general access (it's a testing environment for a site still in production) and I've hit a problem where the multiple file upload feature  fails because it is not correctly handling the authentication; I can see in the Apache logs that the authentication is dropped for the POST

```
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:13 +1100] "GET /index.php/tools/required/files/import?ocID=&searchInstance=file1331694544 HTTP/1.1" 200 8558
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:13 +1100] "GET /concrete/js/swfupload/swfupload.js?_=1331694608575 HTTP/1.1" 200 36807
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:13 +1100] "GET /concrete/js/swfupload/swfupload.handlers.js?_=1331694608601 HTTP/1.1" 200 6443
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:13 +1100] "GET /concrete/js/swfupload/swfupload.fileprogress.js?_=1331694608621 HTTP/1.1" 200 7529
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:13 +1100] "GET /concrete/js/swfupload/swfupload.queue.js?_=1331694608636 HTTP/1.1" 200 3479
10.77.34.123 - testuser [14/Mar/2012:14:10:14 +1100] "GET /concrete/flash/swfupload/swfupload.swf?preventswfcaching=1331694608650 HTTP/1.1" 200 12419
10.77.34.123 - - [14/Mar/2012:14:10:20 +1100] "POST /index.php/tools/required/files/importers/multiple HTTP/1.1" 401 488
```

As a really quick fix I changed the Apache config to only require authentictaion for GET requests, not POST, but that is not desireable from a security standpoint.  The current Apache directive is:

```
<Directory />
  AuthName "Priceline Portal Dev"
  AuthUserFile /home/dev_priceline/passwords
  <Limit GET>
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Which requires basic auth to access to site (via GET) but allows the POSTs through.

What I want to do is change it so:
POST requests containing "multiple" in the URL do not require authentication
All other requests require basic auth.

Is there a way to do this using Apache directives?  The multiple upload functionality is built into the CMS being used, and the basic auth will not be used in final production so I do not want to change the upload code itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's pretty ugly..

```
<Directory />
    AuthName "Priceline Portal Dev"
    AuthUserFile /home/dev_priceline/passwords
    AuthType Basic
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<LocationMatch .*/multiple$>
    <Limit POST>
        Satisfy Any
    </Limit>
</LocationMatch>
```

So, just allow for the auth rules to be ignored (assuming the host is allowed by `Allow`/`Deny` rules) just for `POST` requests that end in `/multiple`, as the one in your log does.  How's that sound?

Comment: Compared to come configs I've seen that's not Ugly at all. :-)